# Why doesn't Django does recognise an app?

Tags: django

I an new to Django and I wrote a program which should print a text in the browser page. I therefore wrote urls.py and views.py, but the browser only shows the welcome page ("The install worked successfully"). What can the mistake be?

Comment: It's hard to say without a [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure to add your app to `setting.py`
2. You must have two `urls.py`; one is for project located in project folder (next to `setting.py`) and the second is inside the app.

You have to use both of them to navigate correctly.

If your app name is `myappname`, then do the followings:

On the main `urls.py` inside your project folder (next to `setting.py`), add:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myappname.urls')),
]
```

On the `urls.py` inside your app add:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import someview

urlpatterns = [

    path('', someview.as_view(), name='name-list'),
    
]
```